# I have an extra line in this figure and don't know how to get rid of it?

Tags: matlab

```
enter code here

format rat
format compact
rng shuffle
```

We begin with the vectors a→=[3 9] and b→=[18 5]
1.)Store these as (column) vectors in MATLAB, and also make a new matrix P that has them as its columns. a as the first, b as the second

```
a=[3; 9];
b=[18; 5];
o=[0;0];
P=[a b];
```

Create a third vector c

```
c=[2;6];
```

create a matrix Q that is like P but now also has c as its third column.

```
Q=[a b c];
```

On the first figure: plot a→ and b→ as vectors starting at the origin (i.e. in standard position).
hold on

```
A=[o a];
B=[o b];
plot(A(1,:),A(2,:))
plot(B(1,:),B(2,:))
```

On the second figure: plot a path connecting a→ to b→.

```
hold off
plot(P(1,:),P(2,:))
```

On the third figure: plot a path connecting a→ to b→ to c→.

```
hold off
plot(Q(1,:),Q(2,:))
```

a)positive, because the cosine of an acute angle is positive
b)Make a matrix M= [a b c a] then plot(M(1,:),M(2,:))
2) try values k=0.1,0.2,…,0.9.  For each value of k, we are going to plot the vector a→−kb→ and see which value of k gives us the smallest one

```
hold on
for i= 1:9
    M=[i*.1*b a];
    plot(M(1,:),M(2,:))
end
hold off
```

Create a second for loop that, instead of plotting a−kb, simply prints its length

```
 for i= 1:9
        norm(i*.1*b-a)
    end
```

Finally, use the formula for vector projections to find the real value of k

```
dot(a,b)/dot(b,b)
```

3. Generate two random vectors in R2 whose entries are integers between 0 and 10

   randi([0 10],[2 1]);
   randi([0 10],[2 1])
   v1=[8;6]
   v2=[2;7]
   v3=(dot(v2,v1)/dot(v1,v1))*v1
   v4=(dot(v3,v2)/dot(v2,v2))*v2
   v5=(dot(v4,v3)/dot(v3,v3))*v3
   v6=(dot(v5,v4)/dot(v4,v4))*v4

Create a single figure that has the following: Each vector v1→ through v6→ plotted from the origin. A polygonal path joining v1→ to v2→ to v3→ to v4→ to v5→ to v6→.
hold off
hold on

```
V=[o v1];
U=[o v2];
T=[o v3];
S=[o v4];
R=[o v5];
W=[o v6];
X=[v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6];
plot(V(1,:),V(2,:))
hold on
plot(U(1,:),U(2,:))
hold on
plot(T(1,:),T(2,:))
hold on
plot(S(1,:),S(2,:))
hold on
plot(R(1,:),R(2,:))
hold on
plot(W(1,:),W(2,:))
hold on
plot(X(1,:),X(2,:))
hold off
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dm6Qu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Running all the code, I don't have the problem. [image: see here]

By looking at the numbers, I think the extra line is from your previous plot

```
for i= 1:9
    M=[i*.1*b a];
    plot(M(1,:),M(2,:))
end
```

You may use `clf` before making the last plot, if you still have the issue.

Comment: what is clf is it like hold on/off

Comment: ALso I made a mistake that was missed i needed #2 to have hold on/ off

Comment: you only need hold on / hold off, if you want to draw multiple plots on the same figure. `clf` clears the current figure. Have a look at the documentation / help in Matlab, it's really useful

Comment: buut i need the figures i just need to separate them